# Object of type OAuthConnection is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, python, django, bigcommerce

I'm retrieving products using the bigcommerce API using the following code

```
def get_bigcommerce_products(request):
    a = api.Products.all()
    return json.dumps(a)
```

I need a response in JSON. So I used json.dumps. But it's giving me the following error '**Object of type OAuthConnection is not JSON serializable**'. I've tried to convert it into a dictionary but not working.

So please help me with this. I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

you need to serialize the objects in the list manually. No json module can do the field traversal for you.
a sample code will be:

```
   l_products =[] 
   for obj in Product.objects.all():
      l_dictObj ={}
      l_dictObj['some_field'] = obj.some_variable
      #...more fields here
      l_products.append(l_dictObj)
```